# Wall Detecting Robot

Tags: circuit-design, simulation, infrared, homework

I am looking to build a robot that will zig-zag back and forth down a hallway. I am wanting to build an IR LED beam and detection circuit so that the robot will detect the wall and change its direction. Does anyone know of a good way to implement this design? Or do you know an example which I could follow?

I could use something other than IR circuit if you have an example or recommendation. 
**No microcontrollers can be used.**

Thanks.

Comment: is this school work? ... `No microcontrollers can be used` indicates that it may be a school assignment

Comment: Not school work. Just trying to design a robot with parts at home and do not have access to a microcontroller currently.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to build it using IR you will face two problems. First, the black color & glass will create a problem. Secondly, sunlight or any other IR source will cause problems. The intensity of sunlight varies randomly. In the case of line follower robots, this factor don't cause much problem as the sensor is under the car.

So, the best way is to use a 22KHz sine wave (with proper DC offset) for the IR LED. And a bandpass filter on the receiver side. (Like tv remote IR transmitter and receiver)

If you can't do that, then buy [TCRT1000](http://embedded-lab.com/blog/introducing-easy-pulse-a-diy-photoplethysmographic-sensor-for-measuring-heart-rate/). Connect the output to a comparator (Non-Invertinginput). And calibrate by giving a reference voltage at inverting input.

Use the op amp output to drive a wheel. Just turning on and off one wheel of two, you can rotate a car.